# Array corrupt on dispatch_barrier_sync

Tags: arrays, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsdata

I have 2 function that append data to Array and a function to process it. I use dispatch_barrier_sync to prevent other function to change the data while I process it.

inside append function:

```
autoreleasepool {  
            dispatch_barrier_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { [weak self] () -> Void in             
                self?.bufferVector_.append(data)  
            }  
        }
```

inside process function:

```
autoreleasepool {  
            dispatch_barrier_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { [weak self] in  
                let len = self!.bufferVector_.count  

                if len > numToExtract {  

                    isMoreInBuffer = true  
                }  

                for bufferData in self!.bufferVector_ {  

                    datas.append(bufferData)  

                    cnt += 1  

                    if cnt == numToExtract {  

                        break;  
                    }  
                }  

                self!.bufferVector_.removeRange(Range(start: 0, end: cnt))  
            }  
        }
```

In above function, bufferVector is array of NSData ( [NSData] )

The function work fine, it just after a while it seem the NSData inside the array is corrupted and I receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS

This is what is show when I try to view bufferVector contents from debugger

```
bufferVector_ = ([NSData]) 8 values  
     [0] = (NSData) 98 bytes  
     [1] = (NSData) 0x16595320  
     [2] = (NSData) 52 bytes  
     [3] = (NSData) 52 bytes
```

I can say it is corrupted because the NSData show memory address instead on bytes length

Cheers

Comment: Unrelated to the question: it makes no sense to use `weak self` and then use `self!`. If you are asserting that `self` can never disappear before this block completes, then use `unowned self`. If you want to ensure that `self` cannot disappear before this block completes (which is what you almost certainly mean here), just use the default (strong) `self`. If you mean "if `self` happens to go away before this runs, ignore it," use `weak` and `self?`. Your current code imposes the costs of `weak` while not getting any of its safety.

Comment: Thanks, I will change my logic regarding that. I probably will pass using strong instead of weak.

Comment: @RobNapier what do you think about using a guard with let strongSelf = self ?

Comment: `guard let strongSelf = self` is often an excellent pattern, particularly for non-trivial blocks. For short blocks, `self?.` is very convenient, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't apply a barrier to a global queue:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_barrier_sync)

> The queue you specify should be a concurrent queue that you create yourself using the dispatch_queue_create function. If the queue you pass to this function is a serial queue or one of the global concurrent queues, this function behaves like the dispatch_sync function.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Rob's answer, you can create a queue that you can either access or pass to either method:

```
let qosClassUserInit                = QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED
let newConcurrentQueueAttributes    = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT, qosClassUserInit, 0)
let newConcurrentQueue              = dispatch_queue_create("SynchronizedArrayAccess", newConcurrentQueueAttributes)
```

Then use it like:

```
// Getting elements
dispatch_sync(newConcurrentQueue) { 

}

// Setting elements 
dispatch_barrier_async(newConcurrentQueue) {

}
```

Related to the comment on your question, I personally like the early return pattern and guarding against self being gone:

```
someBlock { [weak self] () -> Void in

    guard let strongSelf = self else {
    return 
    }
}
```